# How to parse data after specific words

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I have an HTML document:

```
<div class="info">
  Country:
  <b>UK</b>
  <br>
  City:
  <b>London</b>
  <br>
  Name:
  <b>Jon</b>
  <br>
  Date:
  <b>12.08.2014</b>
  <br>
</div>
```

For parsing I use:

```
name = review_meta.search('.info b')[2].text
country = review_meta.search('.info b')[0].text
city = review_meta.search('.info b')[1].text
data = review_meta.search('.info b')[3].text
```

This code is not good, because the order and number of elements can vary.

How can I parse data after specific words?

**UPD:**
[In Nokogiri we can use JS selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856799/nokogiri-mechanize-css-selector-by-text). But in my case parse only first  element anyway.

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = <<_
<div class="info">
  Country:
  <b>UK</b>
  <br>
  City:
  <b>London</b>
  <br>
  Name:
  <b>Jon</b>
  <br>
  Date:
  <b>12.08.2014</b>
  <br>
</div>
_
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

country = doc.at('.info:contains("Country:") b').text
city = doc.at('.info:contains("City:") b').text
name = doc.at('.info:contains("Name:") b').text
date = doc.at('.info:contains("Date:") b').text
puts country, city, name, date # => UK UK UK Uk
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is it always `KEY: <b>VALUE</b>` followed / separated by `<br>`?

Comment: yes. but number of <br> can vary (

Answer (score 1):

How about parsing it with classic regexp:

```
h = {}
str = review_meta.search('.info')[0].text
str.gsub(/[\n]+/, '').split('<br>').reject { |item| item == '' }.each do |item|
  match = item.match(/([a-zA-Z]+):<b>([a-zA-Z0-9\.]+)<.b>/)
  h[match[1].downcase.to_sym] = match[2]
end

p h
=> {:country=>"UK", :city=>"London", :name=>"Jon", :date=>"12.08.2014"}
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting solution. If I do not find another solution, then use it.

Answer (score 1):

> ...the order and number of elements can vary...

If you can't count on the order or structure of the text then you have to do something to break it down until it's usable.

If I thought about it longer I could problem write something more efficient but this is where I'd start:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="info">
  Country:
  <b>UK</b>
  <br>
  City:
  <b>London</b>
  <br>
  Name:
  <b>Jon</b>
  <br>
  Date:
  <b>12.08.2014</b>
  <br>
</div>
EOT

hash = doc.at('.info').text # => "\n  Country:\n  UK\n  \n  City:\n  London\n  \n  Name:\n  Jon\n  \n  Date:\n  12.08.2014\n  \n"
                      .strip # => "Country:\n  UK\n  \n  City:\n  London\n  \n  Name:\n  Jon\n  \n  Date:\n  12.08.2014"
                      .gsub(/\n +/, "\n") # => "Country:\nUK\n\nCity:\nLondon\n\nName:\nJon\n\nDate:\n12.08.2014"
                      .gsub(/:\n/, ':') # => "Country:UK\n\nCity:London\n\nName:Jon\n\nDate:12.08.2014"
                      .gsub(/\n\n/, ' ') # => "Country:UK City:London Name:Jon Date:12.08.2014"
                      .split  # => ["Country:UK", "City:London", "Name:Jon", "Date:12.08.2014"]
                      .map{ |s|
                        a, b = s.split(':')
                        [a.downcase, b]
                      } # => [["country", "UK"], ["city", "London"], ["name", "Jon"], ["date", "12.08.2014"]]
                      .to_h # => {"country"=>"UK", "city"=>"London", "name"=>"Jon", "date"=>"12.08.2014"}

hash['date'] # => "12.08.2014"
```

It breaks the labels and values into a hash, which, at that point you can easily grab individual values.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with xpath, or maybe something like:

```
doc.search('.info').children.find{|x| x.text['City:']}.next.text
#=> "London"
doc.search('.info').children.find{|x| x.text['Name:']}.next.text
#=> "Jon"
```

You want to avoid the other solutions, parsing HTML with regex is a last resort.